# Apache Rewrite module not working correctly

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

Keep on getting below error on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL /application/templates was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 00.0.0.00 Port 80
```

In the error.log showing:

```
No such file or directory in /var/www/html/aplication/api.php on line 228
```

Below are my current rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.html [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?a=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?a=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3

</IfModule>
```

Output for tail -f var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Thu Jun 14 10:30:50.138694 2018] [:error] [pid 7150] [client 172.29.9.57:38776] PHP Stack trace:
[Thu Jun 14 10:30:50.138704 2018] [:error] [pid 7150] [client 172.29.9.57:38776] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/TestCopy_Report1/index.php:0
```

Output for find:

```
sudo find / -iname api.php
 find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
 /var/www/html/application/api.php
 /var/www/html/test1/api.php
 /var/www/html/test2/api.php
 /var/www/html/test3/api.php
 /var/www/html/test4/api.php
 /var/www/html/test5/api.php
```

Comment: This depends on the application you are trying to run. Which one is it?

Comment: PHP web application using PHP5.6.34,mysql5.7.22,apache2.4 and mustache template

Comment: I am sorry, your comment did not provide any information about whether (and how) your application requires the rewrite module.

Comment: rewrite module required to manipulate URLs like 199.99.99.99/abcd/xyz. Same thing working in other local machine but not in new machine.

Comment: So you know you need it? Why don’t you just enable the module then? If there is a difference between two of your machines, then _you_ must find the difference or provide enough information.

Comment: What is the point in down voting this question? Is it not a straight forward?

Comment: Even after enabling rewrite module still 404 exits

Comment: rewrite module is Apache, not PHP.  You also need to *configure* the thing properly to do the rewrites *and* restart Apache afterwards.  If you still get a 404, then you need to start looking at `/var/log/apache/error.log` and such to determine what exactly is going on (i.e. what the server's looking for, etc.)

Comment: In the /var/log/apache2/error.log showing.... No such file or directory in /var/www/html/aplication/api.php on line 228

Comment: So… does the file exist on your machine? We couldn’t check it for you! Or should it be subject to rewrite? How? We don’t know until you post your rewrite rules! The reason I downvoted your question is that it lacks necessary details and you repeatedly fail to provide obviously required information, I am sorry.

Comment: api.php file is exist in the source code repository

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo find / -iname api.php ` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: output is ---- find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied,
/var/www/html/application/api.php,
/var/www/html/test1/api.php,
/var/www/html/test2/api.php,
/var/www/html/test3/api.php,
/var/www/html/test4/api.php,
/var/www/html/test5/api.php

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited your post to include the info from [this comment.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045802/apache-rewrite-module-not-working-correctly#comment1706953_1045802) Note that I have included both the command and the output without the commas which were not part of your output. I recommend in future that when you are requested further information that you not only follow the [advice above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045802/apache-rewrite-module-not-working-correctly#comment1707089_1045802) but also copy and paste the info including both the command and it's output to avoid typos.

Comment: As an example `tail -f var/log/apche2/error.log` is likely a typo. My assumption is that you meant to say `tail -f var/log/apache2/error.log` I'll leave it to you to correct that. Please feel free to use my edit on your find command as a model by issuing the command and then copying and pasting both the command and the output into your [edit]. There's another typo indicated in your error log output. If that is indeed your output then one problem is a typo in configuration that you can easily find with the use of `grep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Added below lines to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

I was required to setup Apache Virtual Hosts.

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: I wasn't completely sure what you meant by "Added below lines", but I figured I needed to append the lines at the bottom of the file below everything.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 18.04 and Apache 2.4.39.

Fullstacks answer didn't work for me, as the default Apache-conf somehow overruled my changes. But, managed to fix this by changing /etc/apache2/apache2.conf directly (using sudo of course):

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I suppose that you didn't mean to remove the initial Directory tag line?

Comment: Good catch! Had that bit on the same line as the three backticks to start a code block, which means it won't show. Updated my answer to show the right code.